# converting String to Character force me to map{$0}, what's the meaning?

Tags: swift, map-function

Writing a randomStringGenerator() function, I came up with this:

```
private let characters = ("0123456789" + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ").characters.map{ $0 }

private func generateRandomChar() -> Character {
  let index = Int( arc4random_uniform( UInt32( characters.count)))
  return characters[index]
}

func generateRandomString(lenght: Int) -> String {
  var string = ""
  for _ in 0..<lenght {
    string.append(generateRandomChar())
  }
  return string
}
```

please note the second line where I use `"0123...".characters.map{$0}`, I'm confuse about the use of this (working) syntax. What does it mean to map and do nothing? Is there a more explicative syntax for the same purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`someString.characters` returns the characters of the string as
a `String.CharacterView`, which is a `CollectionType` indexed by
`String.CharacterView.Index`.

For the `generateRandomChar()` function it is more convenient to have
an `Array` which is indexed by `Int`.

`map { $0 }` is a shortcut notation for

```
map { c in 
    return c
}
```

i.e. a closure with the "identity transform". This is done here
because the `map()` method applied to any sequence returns an `Array`:

```
public func map<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

Alternatively you can achieve the same result with

```
let characters = Array("012 ... XYZ".characters)
```

*Remark:* Your `generateRandomString()` function can be simplified to

```
func generateRandomString(length: Int) -> String {
    return String((0 ..< length).map { _ in generateRandomChar() })
}
```

Comment: Awesome Explaination..!!